# jQuery inside the HighSlide iframe doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, highslide

simple **jQuery doesn't work** inside the **HighSlide iFrame popup**....

Ok... here is exactly what i have:

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>test</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.example.com/plugins/highslide/highslide.css" />
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.example.com/plugins/highslide/highslide-ie6.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <script async src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
     <a href='update.php' onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe', allowWidthReduction: true } )">update</a>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.example.com/plugins/highslide/highslide-full.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.example.com/plugins/highslide/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code of **update.php**

```
<?php
  echo "<head>";
   echo "<script async src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js'></script>";
  echo "</head>";
  echo "<body>";
     ?>
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#isMain').click( function(){
       if(this.checked){
          $('#subCats').hide();
       }else{
          $('#subCats').show();
       }
    });
});
</script>
     <?php
     echo "<form action='' method='post' role='form'>";
          echo "<input type='checkbox' name='isMain' id='isMain'> Is Main Category?<br>";
          echo "<select name='subCats' id='subCats'>";
               echo "<option value='noway'>--SELECT--</option>";
               echo "<option value='1'>Games</option>";
               echo "<option value='2'>Music</option>";
          echo "</select>";
     echo "</form>";
  echo "</body>";
?>
```

But the jQuery Hide Show sometime works fine and sometime doesn't work... what is the exactly issue here ???

Comment: Do you receive any erros in the console? Have you live demo?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery (or any other JavaScript) works in a page that is opened using Highslide iframe [objectType](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.objectType) popup - `objectType: 'iframe'` - since the iframe popup opens the linked page exactly as you have coded it.
Demo using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/rX4Bc/ 
The page used in the iframe popup: http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/UWq3c/